# How to find optimal number of trees in random forest using Grid search in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest, machine-learning-model, grid-search

From below code, I am getting optimal number of mtry. What is this mtry ? and How should I find the optimal number of tree that to be assigned to Random forest algorithm so that it will give High accuracy.

Any comment will be highly appreciated ! Thanks in Advance.

```
classifier = train(form = Survived ~ ., data = training_set_scaled, method = 'rf')
classifier
classifier$bestTune
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mtry` is the parameter indicating how many of the features are checked in each split decision.  http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#random-forest , see method 'rf'

In Random Forest, usually more trees give more stable results, and overfitting *due to* number of trees is rare.  Moreover, since the trees are built independently, you could just fit many trees then take subsets to get smaller models.  But, see e.g. [hyperparameter tuning in mlr](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html) for how to perform grid, random, Bayesian, and other hyperparameter searches, or [grid in caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html) or [random in caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/random-hyperparameter-search.html).